# Error Getting Component Position with ref (ReactCannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, use-ref, scroll-position

I want to get the position of the Skills component and add an animation when the scroll reaches to that point. However, it returns an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null". I followed tried to follow [this blog](https://www.creative-tim.com/blog/web-design/create-scrolling-transformations-react-app/) but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can somebody help me?

Card.js

```
import classes from './Card.module.css';
import React from 'react';

const Card = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <section
      className={`${classes.card} ${props.className}`}
      id={props.id}
      ref={ref}
    >
      {props.children}
    </section>
  );
});

export default Card;
```

Skills.js

```
const Skills = () => {
  const ref = React.createRef();
  const topPos = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  const onScroll = () => {
    const scrollPos = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
    if (topPos > scrollPos) {
      // enter animation code here
    }
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Card className={classes.skills} id='skills' ref={ref}>
      <H2>Skills</H2>
      <div className={classes['skills-list-container']}>
        <div className={classes['skills-list']}>{skillsList}</div>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Skills;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **You are reference to `ref.current` before it gets attached to element**

After creating a ref, you will need to wait for the initial render, then that ref will be attached to an actual element.

By doing like above, you are accessing `ref.current` before the initial render result in a null.

**So just move it inside your `onScroll` function like so:**

```
const onScroll = () => {
  const topPos = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().top;  <-- MOVE HERE
  const scrollPos = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
  if (topPos > scrollPos) {
    // enter animation code here
  }
};
```

---

Moving your `ref.current` to eventHandler body because that handler is only being triggered after the component is completely rendered so ref also already be attached.